# Is having - (id)init not to return itself a good practice?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, init

I am considering the following customized view controller:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil) {
        return self;
    }
    return [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self autorelease]];
}
```

Is this okay?

Comment: This looks OK, but what are you trying to achieve by this design? It sort of kills readability...

Answer (score 5):

This is extremely bad practice. An initialiser method should return an instance of the class that is being instantiated. Always. or `nil` if something is wrong.

If you want to do some extra logic and return a nav controller with the current classes view controller as the root view controller you should look into doing a class method, something like:

```
+ (UINavigationController*)someThing{
    id IdontKnowWhatIsTheNameOfYourClass = [[[[self class] alloc] init] autorelease];
    return [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:IdontKnowWhatIsTheNameOfYourClass] autorelease];
}
```

But even this isn't good practice. Your view controller should know nothing about if it's a modal view controller, inside a nav controller or inside a tab bar controller. Even if you could argue that you would only use that method in the case it should be the root of any of those segues.

To be clear, this will work. But it is very bad.

Comment: Not sure if I am misunderstanding your point, but you can return a subclass of the the object being sent the init message. This is a pattern called cluster classes.

Comment: Sure, but this person's case is returning a `UINavigationController` from the `-init` method of a `UIViewContoller` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a few things. Technically, init methods are allowed to re-assign `self` (which is why you always pair alloc/init in the same assignment). However, **it should be considered terrible design** to return an object of a different class (i.e. one which does not inherit from the class being init'd).

So, unless your class is a *parent* of UINavigationController, I would say your init method is a bad choice.

It might be better to make a class method which is more semantically named and has an appropriate return type (instead of the implicit contract that `init` makes that it will return an object in the same family of the class on which it is called.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice if you have a good reason to do so. It's used by [Class clusters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html) or when trying to use tricky caching mechanism. There is very few reasons to do so and is a pretty advanced thing to do. It's also dangerous if you have a pretty complex superclass.

If you really have to use that trick (instead of just leveraging class constructors), you have to be careful respecting the reference count (if you are not using ARC):

- release the previous instance of self
- make sure the new returned self has a +1 retain count as your client will want to release it once it is done.

E.g. if you want to use some cache of instances:

```
- (id)initWithKey:(NSString *)aKey
{
    id cachedInstance = [__myCache objectForKey:aKey];
    if (cachedInstance) {
        // use this instance instead of self
        [self release];
        return [cachedInstance retain];
    }
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // further init the instance here
        ...
        // cache it
        [__myCache setObject:self forKey:aKey];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You do have a point, but if you consider that his case was from a simple -init method, that's all - (id)init; then there really should be no reason to return anything other then an instance of itself.